# Exporting user input to txt file

Tags: scala, list, input

I can enter data in the form of "DATA > 11,12,54,34,67,23" and it saves to the txt file in this format;

> (DATA > 11,12,54,34,67,23)

However if i try and add another after running this again, this first one is deleted and replaced.
How can i make it so that there are no brackets being saved as my read function does not work with the brackets, and the next one saved goes on the next line instead of replacing the original?

Here is my code

```
  val mapdata3 = readFile("newDataFile.txt")
  var mapdata2 = Map()
  println ("Data in file " + mapdata3)


  // *******************************************************************************************************************
  // UTILITY FUNCTIONS
  //GETS THE DATA FROM THE DATA.TXT
  def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    processInput(Source.fromFile(filename).getLines)
  }
  def processInput(lines: Iterator[String]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    Try {
      lines.foldLeft(Map[String, List[Int]]()) { (acc, line) =>

        val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
        acc.updated(splitline.head, splitline.tail.map(_.toInt))
      }
    }.getOrElse {
      println("Sorry, an exception happened.")
      Map()
    }
  }
  // *****************************************************************************************

  print("Enter Data key > ")
  val key = readLine()

  var result = key.split(";").map(_ split ">") collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) } toMap


  println ("Data entered into file" + result)


  // Writes the newly created stock list to the txt file
  val data = result
  val file = "newDataFile.txt"
  val writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)))
  for (x <- data) {
    writer.write(x + "\n")  // however you want to format it
  }
  writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in append mode. Use [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) instead:

```
public FileOutputStream(File file,
                boolean append)
                 throws FileNotFoundException
```

> append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file
>   rather than the beginning

The rest seems fine, you already have a new line at the end of your write.

Comment: at the end of the Writer val, do I not already call the file output stream?
"(new FileOutputStream(file)" @yǝsʞǝlA

Comment: I mean: new FileOutputStream(file, true)